# How to change font used by ArcGIS Pro controls and dialogues to Khmer?

Tags: unicode, internationalization, arcgis-pro, cambodia

In Cambodia, we need to use Khmer font to show our own language characters. ArcGIS Pro which has Ribbon interface support the display of the Khmer font but we need to change the font to use Khmer font. I am wondering if it is possible to change font used by Ribbon controls and dialogues to the one that support our Khmer Unicode?

In the picture, Khmer displayed properly when we change font to Khmer Unicode while the application dialogues show rectangles, sign of unsupported font.

[image]